# Using wifi to access specific websites that are blocked on the ethernet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, blocking

My workplace blocks access to certain websites (Gmail, Github, etc) while connected to the ethernet. But these are accesible through the less restrictive wifi connection (also provided by my workplace). Since the ethernet is faster, I would let that have higher priority. But, I would like to seamlessly toggle between the ethernet and the wifi connection when accessing one of the blocked sites. I am currently using the solution listed [here](https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/69129-how-can-i-switch-wifi-ethernet-instantly.html) to disable the ethernet using a shortcut on the desktop. 
But, is there a way to implement [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/901362/under-mac-os-x-can-i-choose-to-use-the-wireless-connection-for-some-specific-tr) for windows 10. Going one step further, is there a way to maintain a list of blocked sites somewhere that Windows can read and figure out which connection to use automatically when one of those sites is accessed on the browser?

Comment: If your workplace blocks employees from accessing certain sites on the cabled network, its likely they don't want company computers connected to the less-restrictive wireless network. It would be prudent to confirm this lest you find yourself terminated for violating company policy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Question is specific to an IT-managed computer.

Comment: The solution you linked to can be used on Windows 10.  Why do you believe it does not work on Windows 10?

Comment: The workstation is custom-built and is not IT managed. The network however is IT-managed. Enquiring about efficient ways of navigating the network to accomplish necessary tasks is I think very much on topic for this forum, no? Correct me if I'm mistaken.