# Route all traffic from specific source to take WIFI

Tags: routing, traffic

Sorry for the lack of informations:

1. So, first of all, it's for my working place.
2. I have a laptop wich is connected by a wire. This connection goes throught the network of where I work and then goes into internet. On this wired connection, Spotify is blocked (for reasons).
3. So I thought I could use my smarphone as router (because I have unlimited data and the traffic throug my phone won't be blocked) but just for Spotify so I can work "normally".

The question is:

*Is there a way to make all the traffic from Spotify to go to my smartphone, and for the rest of the traffic, use the normal (wired) connection.*
Hope this is more clear now.

Ps: I precise that this is allowed to listen music to my workplace ;)

PPs:I use windows

Comment: Maybe it is possible. Still, two lines of question body on our displays are really, really few. Can you please add a little bit of description to your scenario? How come that _Spotify_ is blocked on the wired connection?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/901362/under-mac-os-x-can-i-choose-to-use-the-wireless-connection-for-some-specific-tr - Configure your wireless connection as a proxy in your browser.